# monacaアプリで、端末にダウンロード済みのミュージックファイルを使用したい

Tags: ios, monaca

monacaアプリで、iOSのミュージックアプリで聴くことができる音声ファイルを使用したいと考えています。
しかし、実装例や情報が見つからずに困っています。

もしご存知でしたら、ご教授のほどお願い致します。

また、以下の内容についても、合わせて解決できればと思います。
　・Androidでのダウンロード済みの音声ファイルの使用方法
　・Podcastの音声ファイルの使用方法

Comment: 開発環境はmonacaクラウドIDEで外部プラグインも使用できる環境です。  音楽は、自分で再生アプリを作るつもりです。  機能としては再生リスト・早く送り再生・遅送り再生などを考えています。  元の音楽ファイルは読み込みのみ行い、書き換えは行いません。  音量・マイク関連の問題があるのですね。  ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 回答の下にも「コメント追加」リンクがあり、そちらを使うと回答者に通知されるので、回答に対してコメントする際はそちらをお使いください。

Answer (score 0):

環境や、音楽をどうしたいか？などについて記載ください。
`monaca`で上記機能を持った実装を行う場合、外部プラグインが使用できるプランで無いといけません。

また、ミュージックファイルを使用したいと仰ってますが、
再生は出来てもその音楽ファイルを直接どうこうと言うのは難しいです。
(著作の関係もあるためリジェクトの可能性が高い)

もし外部プラグインが使用できるのであれば
[こちら](https://github.com/ghenry22/cordova-plugin-music-controller)のプラグインを使用すれば再生は実装できるかもしれません。

音楽ファイルを……となると再生中に音量最大＋マイク音声取得とか？
どちらにせよ、音楽ファイルを直接扱うのは危険な香りがするのでオススメできません。